# Make a function with functions and call in HTML onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, callback

Here I have a code HTML to onChange run functions so:

HTML

```
<label for="select"></label>
        <select name="select" id="select" onchange="starting();">
          <option>restaurant</option>
          <option>bar</option>
          <option>museum</option>
          <option>gas_station</option>
        </select>
```

With function starting I want to run 2 functions:

```
function starting () {
    route();
    $('#side_bar').empty();
  }
```

But side_bar wont to be empty after changed value to list/menu

Why?

Comment: Where is the element with id=side_bar? It's not visible in the code sample you have supplied.

Comment: Check if `route()` method is throwing any error. Check the console. It could be that route is breaking...

Comment: note: you should avoid inline event binding (`onchange`), use jquery binding techniques

Comment: how to binding jquery ???

Comment: $('#select').change(function(e) { <your code> >});